# Issue faced during management of the Session in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I want to do session handling in my project. I have a login page as
well as register page.
I have stored all the values in the session data and I have destroyed that value at the time of logout using flush function of Laravel.

If the session for the user doesn't exist then the user should be redirected to the Login Page.
To handle this case, I have made helpers.php file in the Controller that checks the data of the session is empty or not.

If the data of the session is empty then the user should redirect to the login page. This case is included in the controller part.
But I'm getting the following error. The implementation of my code is given below:

**Test_laravel\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    //request class is use for take form input
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    //for database
    use DB;
    //to use models
    use App\Crud;


    class CrudController extends Controller {

        public function index() {

              return view('register');
        }
    }

**Test_laravel\app\helpers.php**

    <?php
    // My common functions

            $is_login=session()->get('data');
           // var_dump($is_login);die;
            if(empty($is_login))
            {    
            return view('login');
            }
    ?>
```

The error is given below:

```
**Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object in D:\php\wamp\www\Test_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 105**
```

I need the situation where the user should automatically redirected to the Login page (if they haven't logged in) when they try to access the Register Page.

Comment: Maybe you should start looking for auth at Laravel to understand how login/logout works.

Comment: Check this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#introduction

Comment: Is the code in your `helpers.php` in a function of some sort or is it just dumped in there like that?

Comment: Yes this is the actual code in my helpers.php file if i write the same code in CrudControllers then it is working fine but if write same sort or code in every controller to check whether user is login or not then it increases the complexity of code.So i want to write that session code in my helpers n i have define the helpers path in my composer.json so it will called by default on every controller but it is showing above error.

Answer (score 0):

To Create Cookie

```
\Cookie::queue('admin', 1 , 60);
```

1st Param - Name, 2nd Param - Value, 3rd Param - Cookie Validity Minutes

To retrive the cookie
`use Request; Request::cookie('adminid')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following process to check whether any item say (say user) exists or not rather than creating the helpers.php file as the alternative solution.

**Determining If An Item Exists In The Session**

The has method may be used to check if an item exists in the session. This method will return  true if the item exists:

```
if ($request->session()->has('users')) {
    //
}
```